# SQL - Case when product exists, fill up its corresponding value to all rows within the partition

Tags: sql, partitioning

I have the something like the following monthly data set.

I have a Product, company ID, Date, and Quantity. A company (denoted by Company ID) can buy multiple products. I want to create a new column that will have the quantity of Product 'C' if the company bought in the month at each line item. If Product 'C' is not bought, then return 0.

```
Product Company_ID  Date    Quantity    Desired_Calculated_Column
  A     1         5/1/2019    100                      300
  B     1         5/1/2019    200                      300
  C     1         5/1/2019    300                      300
  A     2         6/1/2019    150                      125
  B     2         6/1/2019    250                      125
  C     2         6/1/2019    125                      125
  A     3         7/1/2019    175                       0
  B     3         7/1/2019    275                       0
```

I have been trying to partition the data based on Product and Company ID. I have been trying to leverage the LAST_VALUE but haven't been successful.

```
LAST_VALUE(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Company_ID 
                           ORDER BY product_group  
                          ) AS Desired_Calculated_Column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `last_value()`.  You can use conditional aggregation, assuming that `'C'` occurs once per group:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN product_group = 'C' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) OVER
    (PARTITION BY Date, Company_ID) AS C_quantity
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. This totally works! Is it possible to edit the query you wrote to set the Desired_Calculated_Column to zero when Product C is bought. However, Product A and B will set to Quantity of Product C like you have done now. Basically the values of Desired_Calculated_Column should like 300,300,0,125,125,0,0,0 in the table I showed above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DataModeler . . . If I understand correctly, use `<> 'C'` as the condition.  If this isn't right, then ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @DataModeler: simply apply a CASE, `case when product_group = 'C' then 0 else MAX(CASE WHEN product_group = 'C' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) OVER
    (PARTITION BY Date, Company_ID) end AS C_quantity`